# Using big endian in struct pack Python with a Pointer

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, endianness, pack

I'm using the struct pack in Python 3.7.
I have this header containing 6 uint32 and one void * argument.

I want to put it in binary format. Unfortunately the interface I'm working on only supports big endian.So I actually need to transform what I send. 
But since P format can't have its endianess modified I always get struct error.
So how can I rewrite this to avoid having this error.

PS: I cannot remove the void * it an mandatory field of my header

```
u1 = 0x4569 
u2 = 0x1236 
u3 = 0x4411 
u4 = 0x1236 
u5 = 0x9696 
point = 0 #(For now) 
data = 0x26358974 
buffer = struct.pack('5IPI',u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,point,data)
```

Actual output

```
buffer = b'\x69\x45\x00\x00\x36\x12\x00\x00\x11\x44\\x00\x00\x36\x12\x00\x00\x96\x96\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x74\x89\x35\26'
```

WHILE what I want would be:

```
buffer = b'\x00\x00\45\x69\x00\x00\x12\36\x00\x00\x44\x11\x00\x00\x12\x36\\x00\x00\x96\x96\x00\x00\x00\x00\x26\x35\x89\x74'
```

Comment: Please update the question with example input and required output.

Comment: The documentation says that `P` is only available for native byte ordering.

Comment: `u1 = 0x4569  
u2 = 0x1236  
u3 = 0x4411  
u4 = 0x1236  
u5 = 0x9696  
point = 0 (For now)  
data = 0x26358974
`  In the current state doing:  
 `buffer = struct.pack('5IPI',u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,point,data) `  
give me :   
 `buffer = b'\x69\x45\x00\x00\x36\x12\x00\x00\x11\x44\\x00\x00\x36\x12\x00\x00\x96\x96\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x74\x89\x35\26' `  
WHILE what I want would be:  
 `buffer = b'\x00\x00\45\x69\x00\x00\x12\36\x00\x00\x44\x11\x00\x00\x12\x36\\x00\x00\x96\x96\x00\x00\x00\x00\x26\x35\x89\x74'  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do this in two stages:

```
u1=1
u2=2
u3=3
u4=4
u5=5
point=6
data=7

# construct two separate buffers
b1 = struct.pack('>5I', u1, u2, u3, u4, u5)
b2 = struct.pack('P', point)
```

Then convert the pointer back to a regular uint, and then back to a pointer:

```
p2 = struct.unpack('I', b2)
b2a = struct.pack('>I', p2[0])
b1 = b1 + b2a
print(b1)
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get this error now :  `p2 = struct.unpack('I', b2)`  
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

Comment: My `b2` is `b'\x06\x00\x00\x00'` which is 4 bytes (little endian of course). What do you have?

Comment: my `b2` is `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`. In the python struct officiel page there is no standard size so maybe i need to force the size myself?

Comment: Sounds like you are on a 64 bit system. What does this pointer mean once it is packed?

Comment: It's a reserved field in order to prevent user to enter unwanted line command in my system.

Comment: If it has no meaning, then you can use an `int` of the right size which *can* be rendered as big endian. Does this help? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490081/convert-a-64-bit-integer-into-8-separate-1-byte-integers-in-python/32490254

Comment: What I end up doing is that instead of `p2 = struct.unpack('I', b2)` and
`b2a = struct.pack('>I', p2[0])` I used `p2 = struct.unpack('q', b2)`
`b2a = struct.pack('>q', p2[0])`

Comment: q(long long) is an integer of standard size 8. Same size as my pointer so. I think I will use this one.